# Remove Play and Pause button for my background video

Tags: html

I tried all the solutions posted on here however nothing seems to work. The start and pause button appears on IOS devices and possibly android. Below is my html and CSS regarding the video.

```css
*::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
  display: none!important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#bg-video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    display: none;
}

#bg-video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="section main-banner" id="top" data-section="section1">
      <video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="bg-video" controls="true" poster="assets/images/backvideo.png">
          <source src="assets/images/course-video.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
          <source src="assets/images/course-video.webm" type="video/webm" />
          <source src="assets/images/course-video.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
      </video>
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<section class="section main-banner" id="top" data-section="section1">
```

```
      <video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="bg-video" poster="assets/images/backvideo.png">
          <source src="assets/images/course-video.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
          <source src="assets/images/course-video.webm" type="video/webm" />
          <source src="assets/images/course-video.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
      </video>
```

Comment: Absolute genius. Thank u

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

...

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
    #videobg:paused {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

since only safari / ios safari support :paused I suggest to put this inside a media query